# Knockout.js, mapping plugin and moment.js - formatting/mapping json dates

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js with the mapping plugin. I am getting some json data and using the mapping plugin to map it into my html.

In the json data is a json formatted date that I need to map into the html using the mapping plugin. Is it possible to use moment.js to format the date and then allow the mapping plugin to map it into the html? How do I get the json date, reformat it to a readable date and map it into the html?

```
// Here is my json formatted date
"DueDate":"\/Date(1362124800000)\/"

// Here's my data model
var viewModel;
$.getJSON('/myJsonData', function (data) {
    viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

// moment.js format date from json - how can this be passed to the ko.mapping?
    var mo = moment("\/Date(1362124800000)\/").format("MMM Do YY");
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an alternative answer, that utilizes a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html). You use it in your View like this:

```html
<span data-bind="textualDate: DueDate"></span>
```

The custom binding code is like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.textualDate = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var textContent = moment(valueUnwrapped).format("MMM Do YY");
        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function() { return textContent; });
    }
};
```

This is convenient because you can use this binding for all Date observables, not just `DueDate`. For example, suppose your model gets extended with other dates, you can easily do this without having to modify your view model:

```
<span data-bind="textualDate: StartDate"></span>
<span data-bind="textualDate: RevisedDate"></span>
<span data-bind="textualDate: DueDate"></span>
<span data-bind="textualDate: WeWillGetSuedPassedThisDueDate"></span>
```

You can check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mncRb/) for a working demo.

Comment: With the mapping options you can also apply the same transformation to multiple properties. Yes a custom binding can be convenient but also you need to remember to use it. If the dates are fixed in the whole UI it is better to convert up front. Anyway your solution is converting on the fly so if the OP wants to display the `DueDate` 10 different places it will convert it 10 times while the mapping plugin only does the convertion once.

Comment: @nemesv True. The answers are different solutions, suitable for different situations.

Comment: Ended up using this solution because the flexibility made the most sense for the project it is used in. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The `mapping.fromJS` method takes a mapping options object in its second argument.

You can provide there a create function ([Customizing object construction using “create”](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)) for the `DueDate` where you do the date conversion:

```
var data = {
    "DueDate": "\/Date(1362124800000)\/"
}
var mappingOptions = {
    DueDate: {
        create: function (options) {
            return moment(options.data).format("MMM Do YY");
        }
    }
};
viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions);
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/n9hcB/)