# Data bind to pre-formatted date field

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a single page application with a number of dialogs, backed by a Knockout view model (with one observable per dialog).

```html
<form id='first-dialog' data-bind='with: firstDialogModel'>
    <input data-bind='value: Name'></input>
    <input data-bind='value: SomeDate'></input>
    ...
</form>
```

And the JS:

```
var vm = {
    firstDialogModel: ko.observable(),
    secondDialogModel: ko.observable(),
    thirdDialogModel: ko.observable()
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

As you'd expect, loading and saving is done via AJAX calls, and simple binding seems to be fine. However, I'd like to format one of the fields as a **dd/MM/yyyy** date for the user and then save any changes back to the database as a regular ISO-formatted date, i.e. **yyyy-MM-dd**

I've tried a number of approaches (computed field, custom data binding etc.), but am currently stuck. Could anyone check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S39kb/1/) and give me a few pointers please?

Comment: Always include the relevant code and markup **in** the question, not just in a fiddle. A fiddle is a nice adjunct, not a replacement for a self-contained question and a [minimal replicating test case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Have you considered using momentJs to format your date?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343747/knockout-js-mapping-plugin-and-moment-js-formatting-mapping-json-dates

Comment: "give me a few pointers" is rather broad. You could try at CodeReview.SE (be sure to read their FAQ though). Aloso, be sure to include all relevant code in your question too, not just in a fiddle (the link may well rot, rendering the question less understandable for future visitors).

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this can get you started ([see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9rtc/6/)), but it does use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). The first pointer that I would give is to use Moment.js for any and all of your client side date/time processing because it is excellent.

Here is how I changed up your custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dateEdit = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        var initialDate = ko.unwrap(observable);

        if (moment(initialDate).isValid()) {
            $(element).val(moment(initialDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        }

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        var initialDate = ko.unwrap(observable);

        if (moment(initialDate).isValid()) {
            $(element).val(moment(initialDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        }
    }
};
```

Note that since you are using an `input` with `type="date"`, the date format must be `'YYYY-MM-DD'` to get it's value to show up in the `input` element (refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770615/setting-format-and-value-in-input-type-date))